# Best approach for AWS Route53 migrate to Terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-route53

I am wondering what would be the best way to manage big set of zones in route53.
The things i wanna benefit here are:

- have zones under version control
- manage zones via code like for example tool Terraform or maybe developing some cli tool for this.
- no manual changes to zones

my problem starts that I have big number of zones in route53 and is hard to track changes and who did what when things start breaking, and i am not sure how i could migrate all into Terraform.

Is there a way to dump current setup into TF ?
Or maybe there is some other better idea how to mange this ?

Comment: I had misread your question: you have a couple of tools that might be able to do this: [terraformer](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer) and [terracognita](https://github.com/cycloidio/terracognita). About other alternatives, it might be that the easier way is to write your own script that reads a config file and replicates that on AWS using the [AWS CDK](https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/). These 2 approaches give you some flexibility in case you need to provision more resources from code.

Comment: @Augusto thx i will try it .. and see where i can get with it ... `terraformer` seems to be power full tool